# Update Language Resource

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, resources, windows-phone

I am trying to update the language items. 
Example:

1. Application started to develop
2. 10 language items are set in default language (English)
3. New language is added (German)
4. All 10 language items in German becomes to be translated
5. Application becomes any update in development
6. 20 new language items are added to default language (English)
7. After compiling, the 20 language items are not available in German language resource.

How to update new items to all language resource in Visual Studio for Windows Phone?

[image: English default]
[image: German added]
[image: German translation]
[image: New item added]
[image: German items missed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new language resource file is created for the first time, it already includes the strings from the default one. But when you add new strings you have to add to all of them.

I have usually done it by editing the default one and copy and pasting the new strings in the other files to edit there.

Fortunately there seems that exists a tool to avoid this tedious task. I havent tried it yet, but following tool allows to edit different string resource files in parallel:

[Zeta Resource Editor](http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/)